# How to pass the currentapple variable into this function?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, webautomation

I have been working on this and have looked at other posts on StackOverflow but they did not answer my questions. This is a unique and specific question. How can I get then currentapple variable to successfully pass into the function? Right now I get undefined src errors. I'm doing web automation with puppeteer and node.js.

Code:

```
    var currentapple = 2;

    console.log(currentapple+" hi1");
    var appleurl= await page.evaluate(async (currentapple) => {
        console.log(currentapple+" hi2");

        var appleelement = await document.getElementsByClassName('ta');
        var appleurl = await appleelement[currentapple].src;
        
        //var gotourl = window.location.href = appleurl;
        //return appleurl;
        
        return await JSON.stringify(appleurl);
    });
```

Error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed:
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined

Comment: Remove the parameter of the anonymous `.evaluate()` handler

Comment: You are shadowing the variable by also using it as parameter; use `var imageurl = await page.evaluate(async () => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must supply the variable as additional parameter for [page.evaluate](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

```
var currentapple = 2;
var imageurl = await page.evaluate(async (currentapple) => {
    console.log(currentapple+" hi2");
}, currentapple);
```